# coffeescript - Can we use coffeescript code inside the view folder of ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I want to use CoffeeScript inside my views folder. As I have  a partial file in my views folder as `_test.html.erb` which is as follows:

```
<canvas id="doughnutChart" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var doughnut = document.getElementById("doughnutChart").getContext("2d");
  var dchart = new Chart(doughnut, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
      },
      options:{
      }
  });
</script>
```

Now I want to have CoffeeScript over here, how can I do that.

Thank you

Comment: May i know why do you want to use coffescript? you can always convert coffescript code to normal javascript syntax? there are various online converter available .

Comment: @Gabbar yes I will use the converter to convert my js into coffee. And why I need because it is the requirement to use CoffeeScript.

Comment: @Gabbar did you get what I asked?

Comment: @shashiverma the same solution you can also use in rails application. Please mark my question as approved answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You it is possible by using the cdn [coffee script cdn](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/coffee-script/1.7.1/coffee-script.min.js)

Or you can visit my js fiddle
[Inline cofeescript inside html](https://jsfiddle.net/swazruby/mnLo3f29/)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/coffee-script/1.7.1/coffee-script.min.js"></script>
        <title>CoffeScript on browser</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

        <script type="text/coffeescript">
          alert 'It works!'
          ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
          chart = new Chart(ctx,
            type: 'bar'
            data:
              labels: [
                'January'
                'February'
                'March'
                'April'
                'May'
                'June'
                'July'
              ]
              datasets: [ {
                label: 'My First dataset'
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                data: [
                  0
                  10
                  5
                  2
                  20
                  30
                  45
                ]
              } ]
            options: {})
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did that like in the question at the place of javascript I have used the CoffeeScript, What I did, I download the `coffeescript.min.js`  file and place it in my `vendor/assets/javascript` folder and require it in my `app/assets/javascript` in `myController.coffee` , then in my partial file at the place of "text/javascript" I used "text/coffeescript" and convert my js code to coffeescript from js2.coffee and place it between the script tag and it works.

Comment: Yes right but you can not put it inline in the same page.

Comment: But I don't think so this approach is good because when I see my source code it is like HTML then CoffeeScript, HTML then CoffeeScript, HTML then CoffeeScript and so on, and the question is hitting in my mind that why the CoffeeScript is not compiled into javascript and all the script should load at the last when all the HTML loading is done. Help me I am confused-_-

Comment: Welcome @shashiverma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184799/discussion-between-mohammad-shahnawaz-and-shashi-verma).